# mysql select related terms

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of dictionary terms and now I would like to create another table which would hold ID of the 'main' term and ID of related terms that have the 'main' term's Name included in their Definition -

```
table: terms 
| id | name | definition |


Table: related 
| term_id | related_term_id |
```

It was pretty easy to create INSERT statements in PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM terms");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM terms WHERE description LIKE \"%$name%\" AND id!=".$row['id']);

    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo "INSERT INTO related(term_id,related_term_id) VALUES(".$row['id'].",".$row2['id'].");";
    }
}
```

However, as I don't have too much experience with MySQL I was wondering if that can be done purely in SQL - let say with use of INSERT-SELECT statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO related (term_id, related_term_id)
SELECT a.id as term_id, b.id AS related_term_id
FROM terms a, terms b
WHERE a.id != b.id
AND b.description LIKE CONCAT('%', b.name, '%')
```

Comment: This will also add the id for `by` and `in` and `LA` in any term that has `Labyrinth` in its description. It doesn't check for whole words, my point is.

Comment: And I don't see why `a.id != b.id` has to be added. A term can have itself in its description.

Comment: Thats true, but that is also what the OP does in his script.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be real slow if the `terms` table is big (more than 1000-10000 rows):

```
INSERT INTO related (term_id, related_term_id)
  SELECT describing.id, described.id
  FROM terms describing
    JOIN terms described 
      ON CONCAT(' ', described.description, ' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ', describing.name, ' %')
```

Assuming all descriptions have spaces separating words and no other marks like `,` or `?` or `!` or `.` If that's not the case, the code will be more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Change your `INSERT` query:

```
echo "INSERT INTO related(term_id,related_term_id) VALUES('". $row['id'] ."','". $row2['id'] ."');";
```